# Got mail with URL pointing to an APK called com.android.fixed.update, what is this?

Tags: apk

One of my relatives sent me an email pointing to this URL:
`http://www.flugversuch.at/cnu/kbdjobbwclikw/nbopigxdb/pxcbaolinizdg/qfktoohwzplsjsp`

When I got there, it automatically downloaded an APK called `com.android.fixed.update`. What could this be and should I install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it really was one of your relatives sending this mail -- and not just a spammer using their address as sender (as the URL suggests)? I would for sure **NOT** install that, to me it looks like malware. Ask that relative first if and why and what he sent.

A [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=com.android.fixed.update&ie=UTF-8) revealed some related information:

- on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766591) one encountered something similar, and they assume it's rather malware
- [BestAppMarket](http://www.bestappsmarket.com/p/app?appId=229295&title=com-android-fixed-update) informs this app was removed from Google Play (hm, guess why). Same information is found at [AndroidInformer](http://xalo-video.android.informer.com/)
- and here it comes: **[VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/2f754a7e127a3f7b633d0f8a71d437af0026ac1dfcd255cc95488e041685ceef/analysis/) clearly lists it as malware**, being detected as such by several malware scanners.

**Conclusion:** Keep your fingers OFF! Do NOT install!